# Double numbers dice

Tags: probability, dice

I was wondering what the odds are that somebody can throw doubles with two dice multiple times.

More specifically, what are the odds one can throw the same eyes with two dice, five times in a row? In this particular case, it doesn't matter what the numbers are (e.g., two sixes and subsequently two fours), as long as the the two dice are equal throws five times in a row.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: You might be interested to know that "dice" is plural.  The singular is "die."  "Dices" is incorrect.

Comment: You know the probability of getting a pair with one throw.  The throws are independent, so use the fact that the probabilty of several independent events all occuring is the product of the individual probabiliites.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting a double on any turn is 1/6 because there are 6 doubles and 36 possible outcomes. Because the 5 events are independent and the probability of each of them occurring is 1/6, the probability of them all occurring is (1/6)^5=1/7776.